# How to access array in if statement?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, scope

I have an admin panel for an application. For this admin panel, the admin has the option to select a user from a dropdown list. When the user is selected, I use an AJAX call to grab the users data and store it in a variable called `$result`. Now when I try to access `$result` outside of the if statement in my HTML file, it is not recognized. What are the possible ways I can access this variable?

HTML file (AJAX call)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#user').change(function() {

    var user_id = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({

            url: 'adminNew.php',
            method:'POST',
            data: {user_id : user_id},
            success: function(data) {

                alert(user_id);

            }
    });
  });
});
```

Php file (if statement)

```
if (isset($_POST["user_id"])) {

    if ($_POST["user_id"] != '') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE user_id ='".$_POST["user_id"]."'";
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

}
```

HTML file (table)

```
<tr>
<tbody id="expBody">
       <?php
        if ($result != ''){
        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '
                 <tr id = '.$row1["id"].'>
                 <td> '.$row1['user_id'].'</td>
                 <td> '.$row1['name'].'</td>
                 <td> '.$row1['email'].'</td>
                 <td> '.$row1['city'].'</td>    
                 <td> '.$row1['state'].'</td>
                 <td> '.$row1['zip'].'</td>


        ';
        }
      }

    ?>
</tbody>
</tr>
```

Comment: Use `echo json_encode($result);` in your PHP file to send the data back

Comment: When you say "PHP file" and "HTML file" - how are you linking these two things together? Are they both included from the same scope?

Comment: I tried `echo json_encode($result); `  but that did not work. When I `console.log(data)` in the AJAX call I get `{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}`

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code needs to send something back to the ajax request

i have seen this done as below before

```
if (isset($_POST["user_id"])) {

    if ($_POST["user_id"] != '') {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE user_id ='".$_POST["user_id"]."'";
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    echo $result;
    die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can load the new table into your #expBody via jquery:

```
$('#user').change(function() {
    var user_id = $(this).val();
    $("#expBody").load("yourphpfile.php?userid="+userid);
});
```

and in your phpfile you actualy "make" the table out of the result..

```
<?php
        $userid = $_GET["userid"];

        // make your db query

        if ($result != ''){
        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '
                 <tr id = '.$row1["id"].'>
                 <td> '.$row1['user_id'].'</td>
                 <td> '.$row1['name'].'</td>
                 <td> '.$row1['email'].'</td>
                 <td> '.$row1['city'].'</td>    
                 <td> '.$row1['state'].'</td>
                 <td> '.$row1['zip'].'</td>


        ';
        }
      }

    ?>
```

that way, this table will be put into your div!